# Creating a web page with a 4x4 grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best method to use to create a webpage with a 4x4 grid that shows different colors in each square on a mouse click?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the 960 Grid system: http://960.gs/
Pretty sure it allows you to specify the amount of columns/rows etc. and then generates the code for you. Might be worth a look.

Comment: A bit open ended. You can add 4 divs and position them with CSS. Then you can use JavaScript to assign click handlers to each. Or better yet, assign the same handler to each.

Comment: What did you try? What exactly is your problem? (HTML? CSS? JS?)
Please see the FAQ on how to ask questions.

Comment: Do you want to use specific colors or just random colors?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is with a `DIV` container with the width of which your site will sit within. For eg. `860px`. Then, create a box class with the style of the grid items. See below [live link](http://jsfiddle.net/aRSNh/) and **HTML** and `CSS`:

**Live link: http://jsfiddle.net/aRSNh/**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing">Test 1</div>
    <div class="box spacing">Test 2</div>
    <div class="box spacing">Test 3</div>
    <div class="box">Test 4</div>

    <div class="box spacing">Test 5</div>
    <div class="box spacing">Test 6</div>
    <div class="box spacing">Test 7</div>
    <div class="box">Test 8</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:860px;
}
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.spacing{
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

As for the different colours on mouse click, if the DIV is a link, you can assign the colours in CSS or, if this is not the case then perhaps a jQuery or Javascript solution might be the way to go. You will need to supply a bit more information to get a more detailed answer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to make a table of cells, then attach onclick event handlers to each one. Here is a 2x2 table to get you started:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables never fail to get the job done EVEN if they get downvoted.

Comment: hahahaha. Quite true. But unless the data is tabular data then DIVs can accomplish the same layout with less markup and more control. There is always a time and a place for tables though =)

Comment: Tables are also responsive by nature, without any additional markup. It's time to bring'em back.